# JSON MERGE coomand needs to change JSON Patch command

Tags: json, mongodb, kubernetes, patch

Basically, I have 3 CR's global,db2 & Mongo. I have to edit these 3 CR's manually to add/enable a service like 'oc edit global, db2 and mongo' then I'll add service details and it works.

- But I need to give a single command to users like a patch command. Below is the method which is a normal process

  oc edit global

  ```
   spec:
     Global:
       backup:
         enabled: true
         name: backup-name
         storageClassName: RWX
         size: 500Gi
   =====
  ```

> ```
> oc edit mongo
>
> spec:
>   statefulSet:
>     spec:
>       template:
>         spec:
>           containers:
>           - name: "mongod"
>             volumeMounts:
>             - name: backup
>               mountPath: '/opt/data/backup'
>           volumes: 
>           - name: backup
>           persistentVolumeClaim:
>             claimName: backup-pvc
>
> =============
> ```

```
oc edit db2

spec:
  storage:
  - claimName: backup-pvc
    name: backup
    spec:
      resources: {}
    type: existing
```

In terms of writing patch commands I succeeded to write [JSON Merge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) command as below:

```
For Mongo:

oc patch MongoDBCommunity staging-mongodb --type=merge -p '{"spec":{"statefulSet":{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mongod","volumeMounts":[{"name":"backup","mountPath":"/opt/data/backup"}]}],"volumes":[{"name":"backup-","persistentVolumeClaim":{"claimName":"backup-pvc"}}]}}}}}}'

For db2:

oc patch db2ucluster staging-db2 --type=merge -p '{"spec":{"storage":[{"claimName":"backup-pvc","name":"backup","spec":{"resources":{}},"type":"existing"}]}}'
```

But above JSON Merge command is replaces/overrides the previous data. So it is not desired method. I see there is a desired way to do is [JSON Patch](https://bijukunjummen.medium.com/json-patch-and-json-merge-patch-quick-example-in-java-c36fdabc2810) where we can use some operations like add, replace, etc., Need help on writing a JSON PATCH command for the above 3 CR's manual step.